# Installing embedded pfsense, stuck at boot loader

Tags: freebsd, pfsense, embedded, boot-loader

I am trying to install pfSense embedded image 1.2.3 RC1 onto a CF card. The box looks like it is ready to boot, but gets stuck at "Loading /boot/defaults/loader.conf" followed by "/". Can anyone provide me a link, or a fix to this issue? Note: I am a router/switch guy, and have no freebsd, or recent sys admin experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's where it switches to the serial console, that's normal. Plug up your serial console and it will continue from there.

Also you shouldn't be using that old release, get 1.2.3 release at a minimum, and 2.0 is preferred at this point.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I have attempted to connect using console and Hyperterm 9600-8-none-1-none, and still stuck at bootloader, and no response in Hyperterm.  I attempted to upgrade to 2.0, and again connected console, but not receiving response in Hyperterm.  Am I using the wrong Hyperterm settings?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was unable to find an embedded version of 2.0, but I was able to install 1.2.3, and get to the menu screen.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a boot loader problem it's essential to provide full information about system's internals:

1. Platform (i386, ia64, powerpc etc)
2. Hardware, especially motherboard
3. BIOS/EFI version
4. GPT/MBR?
5. Filesystem in use (Of cause one can google about "pfsense image",
       download it and search for ufs/zfs, but it would be easier if you
       just provided this information)